# Rounding floats with `E` in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I've got `7,0975401565468943E+22`

And `Math.Round(x, 3)` returns `7,0975401565468943E+22`

Is it normal behavior and should I check if number contains E and if so just use something alike `ToString("N2");` ?

code example:

```
float flo = float.Parse( " 7,0975401565468943E+22 " ); 
double flox = Math.Round(flo, 3);
```

Comment: 7.0975401565468943E+22 is very large positive number (and it can be rational). Math.Round(x, 3) rounds at 3 point after point.

Comment: @al_amanat no, I've added code example

Comment: 7.0975401565468943E+22 is actually very big indeed its actually  7,097,540,156,546,894,300,000.0

Comment: Just to clarify - what were you expecting the output to be? 7.098E+22?

Comment: 7.0975401565468943E+22 is 7097540156546894300000 not 0.00000000000000000000070975401565468943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe appears normal (though without a code example it is impossible to know for sure).

Your number has no significant digits in the fractional portion, as displayed. Note the "E+22", this means that you are dealing with a very large number. There are only 17 significant digits displayed, with another 5 digits not shown before you get to the decimal point. You can round to as many fractional digits as you want, you won't see any change in the number being displayed.